# Retrieve a report as an ado.net datatable

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ado.net

I'm looking for a way to render a report from SQL Server Reporting Services, receive it as a table, I have no access to the SQL backend for this system, don't ask why. The only way I could come up with at the moment is to Render report to a CSV file and convert that. My goal is to retrieve the report data, save it in a SQL Server and do magic on it after I get a copy.

Is there a more elaborate way to do this?

Comment: `"Is there a more elaborate way to do this?"` It depends on what the "magic" is that you want to use Sql Server for.

Comment: The heart of my problem is get the data in a table format in code, what I do with the data afterwards is more around integrating it with other relevant data in a client side application.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying but to me it seems that SSRS might not be the right tool for what you want to do. Could you try to be more specific on what you are trying to achieve. From the idea I get from your question you might want to look into Sql Server Intergartion Services (SSIS).